# How to differentiate $\left(\frac{d}{dt}\left(x\right)\right)^2$?

Tags: derivatives

How does

$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{1}{2}m\left(\frac{d}{dt}\left(x\right)\right)^2+\frac{1}{2}kx^2\right)$ = 0

equals to

m$\frac{d^2}{dt^2}\left(x\right)$ + kx = 0

Comment: @DHMO sorry i entered the wrong answer, it is now corrected

Comment: They are not equal either.

Comment: @DHMO can you show the solution to this question?

Comment: Can you cite your source?

Comment: @DHMO

Conservation of energy : Kinetic(T) + Spring Potential(U) = Constant
. T=1/2mv2, U=1/2kx2
Differentiating by time yields the equation of motion(the final answer)

Comment: Work done is $\displaystyle \int \vec F \cdot \mathrm d\vec s$. I don't see how differentiating by time has any meaning. You mean differentiating by displacement.

Comment: @DHMO Velocity, v = dx/dt, acceleration = (d2x)/(dt2) , the total energy does not change over time thus d(T+U)/dt = 0

Comment: That does not mean you would obtain the lower equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{1}{2}m\left(\frac{d}{dt}\left(x\right)\right)^2+\frac{1}{2}kx^2\right) &= 0 \\ \Longrightarrow \frac{1}{2} m \frac{d}{dt}\big(\frac{d}{dt}x\big)^2+\frac{1}{2}k \frac{d}{dt}x^2 &= 0 \\ \Longrightarrow  m \frac{d}{dt} x\frac{d}{dt}\frac{d}{dt}x+kx \frac{d}{dt}x &= 0 ~\text{ (chain rule)}\\ \Longrightarrow m \frac{d}{dt}\frac{d}{dt}x+k x &= 0 ~\text{ (assuming that $\dot x \neq 0$)} \\ \Longrightarrow m\frac{d^2}{dt^2}x + kx &= 0\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $$1/2m(2\dot{x})\ddot{x}+1/2k(2x)\dot{x}=0$$